# Converting Excel formula to python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with this formula. I am able to understand the condition checking part, the calculation of ($R7/$O7) and default value if condition does not satisfy. What exactly happens inside the PRODUCT(1+($U7:Z7)))-1 ?

```
{=IF($T7>=AA$5,($R7/$O7)/(PRODUCT(1+($U7:Z7)))-1,"")}
```

Also, why do we have {}? If I manually type the formula in some cell, it does not work.

I am trying to convert this formula to python. This is the code I have:

```
df.loc[(df['T'] >= df['AA']), 'x'] = (df['R']/df['O'])/PRODUCT()-1
```

My question is how do I compute the PRODUCT part of this calculation?

Comment: "why do we have {}" - this is an array formula in Excel, typed without the braces and entered by using `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: AFAIK, the PRODUCT function takes in two inputs and multiplies them. Your example has only one (assuming it's formatted correctly - does it return an input in Excel?)

Comment: Yes. It returns a valid response.

Comment: `(PRODUCT(1+($U7:Z7)))` calculates the product of every value+1 in cells U7 to Z7. The  `{}` is needed for adding 1 to every value before calculating the product. The last -1 simply subtracts 1 from the product. CSE-formulas basically works like it first calculates one array (in this case an array where 1 is added to every value) and then performs some other calculation on that array, in this case the product.

Comment: @ayhan I have changed syntax appropriately.

Comment: The product of what cells? Can you provide an example from your df?

Comment: The product of elements of different columns in the same row. I have been trying to select the row elements as an np array to fit in your answer below.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to know how to calculate the product of an array where 1 is added to every value and 1 subtracted from the result it can be easily done with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
product = np.prod(arr+1) - 1
print product
```

Numpy calculations are done array-wise, so adding 1 to every value is simply `array+1`

Based on your updates in the comments this is how its done:

```
df.loc[(df['T'] >= df['AA']), 'x'] = (df['R']/df['O']) / ((df[['a', 'b']]+1).product(axis=1) - 1)
```

Where `a` and `b` are the column names. Notice that this formula returns `NaN` when `df['T'] >= df['AA']` is false.